# scrollbars prevent clicking on icon (on top of icon)

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Took me forever to figure out what was going on. My delete button was not working because the scrollbar click area is on top of the icon.

I'm hoping there's a way to get the click/hover functionality of the trash can when there is no scrollbar in the way. I'd rather not have to push everything in.

I can remove the scrollbar entirely and it works, but I should be able to handle both cases.

Any leads would be great.

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 2):

You should simply add some padding to the element so that the scroll does not overlap the icon.

Comment: Without using `padding` or `margin`.

Comment: padding/margin makes the most sense here.  Two other options include: remove custom scrollbar (browser scrollbar won't block click), or change where the click happens (ie: swipe right or right click context menu depending on target platform).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that as the scrollbar only needs to appear when you scroll. (if on mac, lion+) try making this page really small and hover over "Related" links. You'll notice they still are clickable, even though we're in the scroll region. As you scroll and hover, the scrollbar's hover event takes precedence. Right now I'm looking at the custom scrollbar route, as this will probably be a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, DMoses, that **is** the default scrollbar on Mac. They're that design-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some padding but probably it would be best (though annoying) to use a custom scrollbar.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment but I did try to.

Comment: We've all been there, just answer what you can till you can comment.

Comment: basically, the scrollbar is covering the trashcan, so it's not clickable (except for tiny bit on right). looking for more of a technique rather than specific code.